# Gmail won't retrieve emails automatically after lollipop 5.1 upgrade

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sync, gmail, 5.1-lollipop

I have a Motorola Moto 4G 2nd gen and since purchase I have used google's gmail application for my email. Everything worked fine. I would receive emails very quickly without having to do much.

However, after some problems with my phone I upgraded to lollipop (5.1) and what a disaster. The biggest problem is it now doesn't automatically download my emails. I seem to have to visit "Social", or "Promotions" and then click back in to "Primary", which seems to trigger a sync and find my awaiting email.

How on earth can I fix this? I cannot spend my day having to do just between Primary and Social to check whether I have an email or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your setting for Sync is disabled. Enable the setting for Sync in Status-bar.
Hope your problem may be solved.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing and re-adding your Google Account.

Settings > Accounts > Google.

Remove it, reboot the phone, and then go through the process of re-adding it.